# How to prove the condition of commutativity of the product of two square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning

There is a question in my textbook as follows:

> Prove that for a square matrix $A$ to be commutable with any other square matrix $B$ (meaning that $AB=BA$), it is necessary and sufficient for $A$ to be a scalar matrix(i.e., to be of the form $cI$, where $c$ is a scalar and $I$ is the identity matrix).

I have proved the sufficiency part as below:

Given $A=cI$

Then $AB=cIB=cB$ and $BA=cBI=cB$.

Hence, it is proved that $AB=BA$.

But I cannot prove the necessity part, i.e., given $AB=BA$, I cannot prove that $A$ is of the form $cI$.

Please anyone help me solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I can't understand the notations there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint to get you started:

You know that $A$ commutes with all  matrices $B$. It thus also commutes with elementary matrices (matrices that are $1$ on one position and $0$ elsewhere). What can you conclude from this?

Comment: Please explain a bit more. I can't understand. I have viewed all the other answers, but still it is not clear to me.

Comment: Ok. Take your matrix $A$. Consider the matrix $E_{11}$ that is $1$ on position $(1,1)$ and $0$ elsewhere. What do you get when you calculate $AE_{11}$ and $E_{11}A$?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it's clear to me.

Comment: Yes, the key to finish is now to use that $AE_{ij} = E_{ij}A, i \neq j$, forcing all diagonal elements to be equal. Glad I could help.

Comment: In terms of abstract algebra, this means that the center of the real matrices are the diagonal matrices with constant diagonal.